# Find duplicate values across rows, Python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I would like to find duplicate values across rows. e.g. row 1 has 3 duplicates (A). Keep the first value (or keep any one of them), and replace the other duplicate values with nan

|  | col1 | col2 | col3. | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | A | Y |
| 2 | B | D | G | L |
| 3 | E | F | T | K |

```
data = {'col1':['A', 'B', 'E'],
        'col2':['A', 'D', 'F'],
        'col3':['A', 'G', 'T'],
        'col4':['Y', 'L', 'K']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please when asking about dataframe, provide python code to reproduce your problem exactly, provide the DataFrame construction with data, so we can do it without writing by ourself. Also show the expected output exactly, that avoid failing to understand the text ;)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pandas.DataFrame.transpose()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) then check duplicate on each column.

```py
df_ = df.T

for col in df_.columns:
    duplicated = df_.duplicated(col)
    df_.loc[duplicated, col] = np.NaN
```

```
# print(df_.T)

  col1 col2 col3
0    A  NaN  NaN
1    B    D    G
2    E    F    T
```